# JavaScript, what does immediately invoked function in this particular case?

Tags: javascript

```
 (function(){
function byId(id) {
   return document.getElementById(id);
  }
  byId('submit').onclick = function() {
         ((more code here.....))

   };
})();
```

when I remove the function that wraps the rest of the code inside, then the script does not work. Could any kind person explain to me what does that anonymous function at the top? Why the script does not work without it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer self-invoking anonymous function (*iffy*) will do what the name suggests. It'll call itself immediately at run-time. So in conclusion to that, I assure you, the inner script will work the same way removing the outer function (as long as there are no other scripts around which might influence your code).

Answer (score 0):

The function wrapper simply avoids polluting the global `window` object with `byId`. If removing this protection the page doesn't work it means someone else uses that name at the global level.